# Ionic Android App working on some devices only and showing only blank screen after splash screen on some other devices

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

I'm developing an app, I have android devices(Android 9, 10) and emulator to test. Its working fine in my devices and emulators but its not working on client device(Android 9, 10).

My Ionic Info:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.13.1 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1101.4
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.1.4
@angular/cli                  : 11.1.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : 6.0.0, android 8.1.0, browser
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 4 other plugins)

cordova-res                          : 0.15.3
native-run (update available: 1.3.0) : 0.3.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS            : v12.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 6.13.4
OS                : Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried to debug the issue using chrome://inspect in the chrome browser?

Comment: Yeah i found a solution by taking a app build under production. (ionic cordova run android --prod)

Answer (score 0):

If the screen remains blank (i.e. the app keeps running) it's probably a Javascript error, but just in case, try to run the app with debug configuration and [inspect the LogCat messages using Android's SDK **DDMS**](https://www.andreszsogon.com/debug-cordova-android-apps-with-ddms/).

[image]